# Why did Ben send Ethan to the wreckage?

Tags: lost

When Oceanic flight 815 crashes, Ben sends Ethan to the front section and sends Goodwin to the tail section.

Ben wanted Goodwin to die. Juliet makes it clear that Ben knew Goodwin would die. So did he plan for Ethan to die too? I just watched season 4 episode "The Other Woman" as reference.

Ethan was the main doctor for the others, would Ben send him away to be killed? Why not send someone like Tom?

Comment: How did Juliet know Goodwin would die?

Answer (score 1):

Ben did not plan for Ethan to die.  Ben wanted information about the crash survivors.

http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Ethan

Ethan's skills were necessary to Ben and his plans.

Comment: How do you know this? Could you give us some evidence with some quotes?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not canon but is part of how I understand it and how I see it.

Ben wanted to have full control of the island and everyone in it. The actor is perfect for that role. When you live in an island like the one in lost when since Dharma initiative left no one ever really comes and suddenly a plane crashes there you really need to check up on them and see who they are, what they are etc. So he sent Ethan a man with a specific set of skills that really suit the task in order to blend in and get the most information possible about them.

**edit**
By skills I mean that he was a surgeon and a doctor so he would more easily help, blend in and gain their trust unlike the others. Also Ben worked with him in kidnapping Alex so Ben trusted him more for a job like this than other doctors (Juliet)

Comment: What specific skills did Ethan have that made him the optimal person to send?

Comment: @curiousdannii edited my answer with more info

Comment: I can also explain it like that. I also reminisque that Ben stated that Ethan's death was not planned or intended. //EDIT: The more I think about it, I guess this has been stated in one of the making-ofs.